# Capturing jQuery change event repeatedly for select on same index

Tags: jquery, onchange

There is a neat little feature in jQuery (or the browsers, I'm not sure anymore) that, when you use the keyboard to navigate a select element, makes sure the jQuery "change" event does not retrigger when you press enter multiple times.

This is all good and fine, but I'm working on a multi-selectable list, where chosen elements are removed from the list and added below. This leads to the problem that you cannot select the item at the same index as the previous item you selected (using the keyboard only) because they are seen as identical.

In IE, I can solve the problem by resetting the comparison data with the following code at the end of the change event:

```
jQuery.data(this, "_change_data", null);
```

I don't know why it only works in IE. Is there any way to make repeat selections for the same index to each trigger a change event?

**Solution:** A simple workaround was simply to disable the selected values rather than removing them from the list.

Comment: Can you give link to demo or put it on jsbin

Comment: I added the workaround I ended up using, to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it - but I think this might help:

event.preventDefault()

I have seen it used for mouse-clicks - but I think it should work for all events. However, I think it relies on the browsers correctly implementing their event behavior - so there might be cross browser issues.